metadata-generation-failed when installing tf-models-official
I'm trying to install tf-models-official with !pip install tf-models-official and when it started to collecting kaggle>=1.3.9, it returned error below :
Collecting kaggle>=1.3.9 (from tf-models-official)
  Using cached kaggle-1.6.15.tar.gz (9.1 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [35 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-fqrzl9xw/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/hatchling/build.py", line 58, in build_wheel
          return os.path.basename(next(builder.build(directory=wheel_directory, versions=['standard'])))
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-fqrzl9xw/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/hatchling/builders/plugin/interface.py", line 155, in build
          artifact = version_api[version](directory, **build_data)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-fqrzl9xw/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/hatchling/builders/wheel.py", line 475, in build_standard
          for included_file in self.recurse_included_files():
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-fqrzl9xw/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/hatchling/builders/plugin/interface.py", line 176, in recurse_included_files
          yield from self.recurse_selected_project_files()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-fqrzl9xw/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/hatchling/builders/plugin/interface.py", line 180, in recurse_selected_project_files
          if self.config.only_include:
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-fqrzl9xw/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/hatchling/builders/config.py", line 806, in only_include
          only_include = only_include_config.get('only-include', self.default_only_include()) or self.packages
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-fqrzl9xw/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/hatchling/builders/wheel.py", line 260, in default_only_include
          return self.default_file_selection_options.only_include
        File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p310/lib/python3.10/functools.py", line 981, in __get__
          val = self.func(instance)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-fqrzl9xw/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/hatchling/builders/wheel.py", line 248, in default_file_selection_options
          raise ValueError(message)
      ValueError: Unable to determine which files to ship inside the wheel using the following heuristics: https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/plugins/builder/wheel/#default-file-selection
      
      The most likely cause of this is that there is no directory that matches the name of your project (kaggle).
      
      At least one file selection option must be defined in the `tool.hatch.build.targets.wheel` table, see: https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/build/
      
      As an example, if you intend to ship a directory named `foo` that resides within a `src` directory located at the root of your project, you can define the following:
      
      [tool.hatch.build.targets.wheel]
      packages = ["src/foo"]
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I was able to install 2 weeks back, now on the new jupyter notebook kernel suddenly not able to install. I've tried to reinstall on the old kernel, the same error happens too. Anyone know how to solve this?

What is the name of your project?

This is a problem in the kaggle python package https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api/issues/611

Update :
kaggle released kaggle 1.6.17 on Jul 25, 2024.
Now,
pip install tf-models-official

is working with tf-models-official 2.17.0

Old answer
tf-models-official 2.17.0 was released on Jul 17, 2024


It is using kaggle-1.6.15.
There is a issue going on kaggle-1.6.15 as discussed here :
https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api/issues/611
For now you can use:
pip install tf-models-official==2.16.0

Until kaggle-1.6.15 is fixed.
